# Extracting Data from from String on C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I have following strings:

Temp: 25.50 Humidity: 49.00
Temp: 30.50 Humidity: 50.50 Pressure: 500.00

I would like to store only the numbers (for example 25.50 and 49.00) in two different variables on C#. Any hints please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My data is coming from Hardware on Serial port.

Comment: Then you can use Regex....

Comment: Do you only want Temp/Humidity? Do you want only the *first* readings of temp/humidity? Do you want all of them? You need to clarify your question with more details. Also, show the code that you've tried already.

Comment: I am using it but giving me
25   
50
49

Comment: All separate numbers

Comment: Show your code....

Comment: string value1 = rx_data;  
                var data = Regex.Match(value1, @"[0-9]+").Value;
                //string[] data = Regex.Split(rx_data, @"\D+");
                /* foreach (string value in value1)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        float i = float.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
                    }
                } */
                Console.WriteLine(data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
string input = "Temp: 30.50 Humidity: 50.50 Pressure: 500.00";
var values = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+\.\d+")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => float.Parse(x.Value,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate that. It seems like very complex lengthy commend.